# Cannot disable WTF CSRF protection during testing

Tags: python-2.7, unit-testing, flask, flask-wtforms, csrf-protection

I cannot work out how to disable the CSRF protection while I am conducting my unittesting.

My `test_login()` function fails the unittest. When I debug I can see that in the Form the `csrf_enabled` value is set to `True`

The documentation states that `app.config['WTF_CSRF_ENABLED'] = False` should be sufficient however that does not appear to be working

Can anyone advise how I can disable CSRF protection?

Thanks

```
from flask.ext.testing import TestCase
from flask import Flask
from Shares import db, app as appy
from Shares.models import User
import manage


class test(TestCase):

def create_app(self):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config['TESTING'] = True
    app.config['WTF_CSRF_ENABLED'] = False
    return appy

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = "sqlite://"
TESTING = True

def setUp(self):

    manage.initdb()
    print self.login('lucas', 'test').data

def tearDown(self):

    db.session.remove()
    db.drop_all()

def login(self, username, password):
    return self.client.post('/login', data=dict(
        username=username,
        password=password
    ), follow_redirects=True)

def logout(self):
    return self.client.get('/logout', follow_redirects=True)

def test_adduser(self):

    lucas=User(username="lucas", email="lucas@example.com", password="test")
    user2 = User(username="lucas", email="lucas@test.com")

    db.session.add(lucas)
    db.session.commit()

    assert lucas in db.session
    assert user2 not in db.session

def test_login(self):

    lucas=User(username="lucas", email="lucas@example.com", password="test")
    db.session.add(lucas)
    db.session.commit()

    rv = self.login('lucas', 'test')
    assert 'Welcome' in rv.data
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've worked it out.

I just had a typo in my variable name app & appy

```
def create_app(self):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    appy.config['TESTING'] = True
    appy.config['WTF_CSRF_ENABLED'] = False
    return appy
```